# Disabled textarea in I.E7 Doesnt have a scroll bar how to fix

Tags: asp.net

Is there a way to force IE7 to show a scroll bar even when the textarea is disabled. This works fine in firefox but doesnt in IE7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

with css:

```
#element
{
    overflow:scroll;
    overflow-y: scroll; //ie specific
}
```